# How to make firefox command autcomplete SVG file paths when I press tab key

Tags: command-line, firefox, gnome-terminal

I have Mozilla Firefox 95.0.1 running on Ubuntu 20.04. I need to open some SVG files that contain animations in the firefox browser using the command line as follows:

```
firefox <Tab Key>
```

The filenames are generally long and I don't want to copy paste them or type them manually,  so when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key multiple time I would like the filenmae to be autocompleted but in my case nothing happens.

How can I make firefox command on the terminal autocomplete SVG file paths by Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key?

Comment: You can also press `M-/` to complete a filename ignoring the `bash-completion` rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the `bash-completions` definition for Firefox. If you need autocomplete support for a limited number of files, then something like this would work:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open the appropriate completions file for Firefox with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/firefox
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Around line 42, you will see this:

   ```
   _filedir "@(?([xs])htm?(l)|pdf)"
   ```

   This is the line that controls what sort of file extensions are available as an autocomplete for Firefox. Here we can see support for `.htm`, `.html`, `.xhtm`, `.xtml`, `.xshtm`, `.xshtml`, and `.pdf`. You can add additional file extensions after `pdf`:

   ```
   _filedir "@(?([xs])htm?(l)|pdf|svg|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)"
   ```

   Here I've added `.svg`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, and `.gif`. Feel free to add/remove as needed.
3. Save the file.
4. Reload your bash source:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Alternatively, you can close the terminal and re-open it. If you have any other Terminal windows (or SSH connections) open, then the source will need to be reloaded in each before they can use this autocompletion.</sup>

**Additionally ...**

If you would like autocomplete to allow *any* file to work with Firefox regardless of the browser's ability to render the information, then you can remove everything after `_filedir` to leave a blank:

```
_filedir
```

This will allow you to autocomplete nonsensical things like:

```
firefox ~/Documents/backup.sql.gz
```

Comment: Looks very nice, but you are changing system files controlled by the APT system. Probably copying the file to `/etc/bash_completion.d` and changing that copy will be a better approach: that file will take precedence and will not to be reverted by future updates.